# PHP: getaddrinfo failed when trying access a 1&1 database from a local web app

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an issue when I try to access my 1&1 database from the local web app I am coding.

Output: Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown host.

I use mysqli (which works great with a local database) to connect my app with the DB and I already know the php5 issue with mysqli and 1&1 servers but this would occurs only if my app where on my server.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("dbxxxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com", "dboxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "dbxxxxxxxx", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else
{
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
}
```

Maybe the issue comes from the way I write the host, I tried to add "http://" before but the problem was the same.

Thanks for helping me! :)

Comment: If you have access to the command line, try `dig dbxxx.db.1and1.com` and see if it resolves

Comment: `Unknown host` mean the hostname doesn't exist in DNS. Double check that you've typed it correctly. If it's newly created it might take a few minutes before its effective, and if you looked it up before it was effective you might have to wait a few minutes the the [negative cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_cache) entry to expire.

Comment: Machavity I tried and it gave me this: 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> db388296648.db.1and1.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52952
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;db388296648.db.1and1.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
1and1.com.  3503 IN SOA rns.ui-dns.de. dnsadmin.1und1.de. 2013085787 10800 3600 604800 86400

;; Query time: 78 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 12 11:18:36 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106

Answer (score 0):

Seems a name resolving problem. If you use Linux/MacOS, add the hostname and its IP address in hosts file:

```
# echo "123.123.123.123  dbxxxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

You must replace this example IP for the real one.